# Working with WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, bison, flex-lexer

I have a project that requires using flex and bison (with c++) - I do it with unix beacuse it's comfortable (just using flex, bison and g++). I need to use some 'graphic' library for my project and decided to go with WinApi. My question is: 
I want to include some functions based on WinApi in bison file -> generate parser, then generate scanner with flex, and compile these files with g++. I understand that this 'executive' program won't work with linux, but will it work with windows (I ask because it would compiled with linux). If not, is there an easy way to use flex, bison and g++ with windows that would generate the same output as with linux?

Comment: You'd be much better off finding a linux UI library you could use, rather than trying to crosscompile windows code from a linux box. Testing would be a nightmare! wxWidgets might be an easyish option, but asking for window library suggestions is outside of the scope of SO questions.

Comment: FYI, the "flex" tag refers to Apache Flex, a programming framework for Flash.  For questions regarding flex and bison, the "flex-lexer" tag is the one to use.

Comment: You can certainly compile the files generated by bison (and flex) on Windows, regardless of where you run bison and flex. Although it seems like it would be easier to run bison and flex on the same system you use to compile the resulting files, which is certainly possible even if that system is Windows.

Comment: I managed to make it work with windows, thanks for the answers. Just have one quick question. I include e.g. "hello.h" file to bison.y and I want to invoke my function with declaration in hello.h and definitions in hello.cpp. Bison definitely sees the class in that file, but can't invoke any method: "undefined reference to Hello::zwroc()". Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't work. If you include WinAPI stuff, g++ wouldn't be able to compile it, and even if it could, it wouldn't work on Windows. If you mean the output files from flex/bison, these will compile on any standard platform as they're 'mostly' standard conformant code.

It's easy enough to use flex/bison with Windows. There's several ports of it, like [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/), but you can also use it with Cygwin. They work just like the Linux versions.

You can find an example on how to integrate Flex/Bison tools with Visual Studio [here](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/flex_and_bison_in_msvc.html)